# Vocabulary question

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking at a picture saying "Detroit Fire Engine Company 22", and it looks like a fire station. But is it ? For me "fire engine company" refers to a company making fire prevention stuff like extinguishers. Have you any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting it up in the wrong place.  It is a "Detroit Fire Engine" used by "Company 22".  A [fire company](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fire-company) is "a company of firefighters", so this is a [fire engine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fire+engine) used by the firefighters in Company 22.

Comment: I suspect that in this instance *Fire Engine Company* is the intended construction: a company of firefighters which uses and maintains a fire engine.

Comment: Company - "_a body of soldiers, especially the smallest subdivision of an infantry battalion, typically commanded by a major or captain._" Derives from a similar place no doubt?

Comment: @StoneyB: Could you possibly provide a link with a definition?  Looking up `definition "fire engine company"` isn't coming up with anything.

Comment: @zondo I wouldn't expect this to be entered anywhere as a distinct 'headword', any more than *tank battalion* or *stealth bomber squadron*. You're quite right that *company* here designates a body of men rather than a commercial firm.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj34tTyjI7MAhXMFj4KHXEVCz4QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEngine_Company_9_Fire_Station&psig=AFQjCNEvt1XcPinBHJDvjvdQfufsYfiGzA&ust=1460722230079870